# How to Correctly Reference Rust Module And Method

Tags: rust

In my main.rs, I have :

```
mod Connection.rs;
...
fn update(&mut self, message: Message) -> Command<Message> {
        match message {
            Message::Session() => {
                println!("Session Pressed");
                Connection::new();
            }
        }

        Command::none()
    }
...
```

In Connection.rs, I have :

```
impl Connection {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let stream = Connection::connect(String::from(""), String::from(""));
        Connection { 
            stream,
        }
    }

    fn connect(ip:String, port:String) -> Option<TcpStream> {
        None
    }
}
```

Why can't main see my Connection::new() method?

Comment: It should be `mod Connection;` without the `.rs`, and then you'd use `Connection::Connection::new` - module name followed by type name followed by method name. Note that in Rust it is customary to use short all-lowercase names (snake_case) for modules.

Comment: Okay awesome. I see now. If you’d like to make that an answer, i’ll accept it. Is everything snake_case? I ask because I see a lot of online having Capitalization for Structs. Or is it just for the module names?

Comment: Modules, functions, methods, and local vars are snake_case; types, traits, and enum variants are CamelCase; constants and global vars are SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE. But don't worry about that too much, the compiler will warn you if you make a "mistake". Just listen to the compiler and you'll be fine. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm switching from Swift (iOS Dev) which has a bit of a different culture. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: No problem - have fun with Rust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `mod Connection;` without the `.rs`. The compiler will then automatically look for either a `Connection.rs` or a `Connection/mod.rs`. Access the `new` method with `Connection::Connection::new` - module name followed by type name followed by method name. Or, you can add `use Connection::Connection` to `main.rs`, in which case you can access the method as just `Connection::new`.

Note that in Rust it is customary to use short all-lowercase names (snake_case) for modules - see the [style guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/naming/README.html#general-conventions-%5Brfc-#430%5D) for details, or just take notice of the warnings issued by the compiler.